# Which one would you choose ; XCache or APC?

Tags: php, apc, opcode-cache, xcache

I need a opcode-cache in my project. Also i will use for the datastore (mysql returned row) cache ? Which is the best for you and WHY ?

Comment: See this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache

Answer (score 10):

I'd choose [APC](http://www.php.net/apc), but only because [it's being adopted as part of PHP 6](http://davidwalsh.name/php6).

There are also some good opinions offered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache).

Comment: Indeed, and I still recommend APC. Memcache has some interesting features - distributed caching but no opcode cache.

Comment: Facebook uses APC very heavily -- so suffice it to say, it's pretty soundly proven in production environments.

Comment: Since this comment, APC has been dropped off PHP, in favor of OPcache, in PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

I use XCache because it was written by the same person who wrote lighttpd, which was written for **SPEED**. Works on apache, also.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I've had great success (reliability-wise and performance-wise) using XCache. I also use it in conjunction with memcache to speed up session operations and cut down on hits to MySQL.