# What's APC alternative to?

Tags: php, apc

APC (as in https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) stands for Alternative PHP Cache. What is it alternative to - is there another, built-in caching framework in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in OP-Code or variable cache built in.  But there are a [number of alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)...

I believe it was an alternative to the proprietary (and commercial) Zend Cache which was around in the late '90s and early 2000's.  There are a number of different accelerators out there now (each with their own advantages and disadvantages), but in the early 2000's, the main one was Zend Cache.  So I would assume (the time scales look right) that APC was meant to be an alternative to Zend Cache (an open source and free alternative)...

Answer (score 2):

[Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) is also widespread.

Also see this [List of PHP accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) which speak of:

- Alternative PHP Cache
- eAccelerator
- ionCube PHP Accelerator
- Turck MMCache
- XCache
- Nusphere PhpExpress
- Zend Accelerator
- Zend Platform
- Windows Cache Extension for PHP

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to not using one at all?

Seriously though, maybe as an alternative to eAccelerator and Xcache?

Also see: [apc vs eaccelerator vs xcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache)

Answer (score 0):

OPcache is the alternative and it's available since PHP 5.5

http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php