# Where can I find tutorials on Facebook's XHP extension for PHP?

Tags: php, xml, facebook

I'm very interested in the Facebooks php extension xhp (http://github.com/facebook/xhp/wiki), but I didn't use it so far.

I was wondering if anyone can share personal experience with xhp and point me into direction where I can find tutorials about it (wiki on github is very poor).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

- [Installing, Configuring, and Using the XHP PHP Extension by Facebook](http://calvinf.com/blog/2010/installing-configuring-and-using-the-xhp-php-extension-by-facebook/)

Answer (score 0):

php.net provides a pretty good all-around [tutorial on compiling PECL-style extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php).  This is how you'll install xhp.

In my experience, it's really a joy to use.  And the safety net that is XHP's automatic, context-aware escaping is a real aspirin-saver.

That said, you can incur pretty hefty penalties for using XHP.  Personally, I wouldn't touch it without [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache) installed.  See [Lerdorf's anecdote on the topic](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/54-A-quick-look-at-XHP.html) of performance.

Overall, if you have the time, I'd definitely recommend trying it out.  Only data will tell you if it's right for your site, though.  And, as always, [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=install+xhp).

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't put much effort in trying xhp, but it is still very interesting stuff. Definitely I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good information on [**XHP by a Facebook Engineer**](http://codebeforethehorse.tumblr.com/).