# How Find Concurrent request per second made to server using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, typo3, awstats

Our website is being  running for the past 6 months.
I would like to know how to detect concurrent users we are serving or the requests per second we are getting" so that we can do some performance tweaking.

We use Apache, PHP(Typo3 CMS), Google Analytics and AWStats.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Google Analytics Interface has an option to view the users in real time.
This will only show you the views to your HTML ages though (or any call to GA, like file downloads if configured).
It will not show you people accessing assets such as images, CSS or javascript files.

To increase the performance of TYPO3 there are a couple of things to consider:

- USER instead of USER_INT plugins
- if a user is logged in, switch the caching of the extension with a condition (see code at the end, SO doesn't like code in bullet lists)
- use a PHP cache such as APC, see this discussion: [apc vs eaccelerator vs xcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache)
- use a reverse proxy, such as varnish in combination with the TYPO3 extension [moc_varnish](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/moc_varnish/current/)

---

```
plugin.tx_myplugin = USER
[loginUser = *]
plugin.tx_myplugin = USER_INT
[global]
```