# Is it still worthwhile to install the 'eaccelerator' PHP compiler cache?

Tags: php, eaccelerator

Back in the PHP 4 Jurassic Era, I often installed a PHP extension called 'eaccelerator' to boost the performance of PHP by caching the compiled byte code.

I've read elsewhere that with PHP 5, the need for add-ons like eaccelerator has decreased, but is there still enough of a speed difference to make it worth installing on Linux servers?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, opcode caches still make a **dramatic** performance difference.
Most are using [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) over [eAccelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eaccelerator/) these days, though.

Comment: -1, if you able to indicate eaccelerator is still active, I will more than happy to take that back

Comment: @ajreal Your comment doesn't make much sense. eAccelerator's website doesn't seem to even work anymore. http://eaccelerator.net/ APC benefits from being installable via PECL and documented on PHP.net, too.

Comment: I dun know what is more making sense by recommend something semi-retired

Comment: Uh, I didn't recommend eAccelerator. I recommended an opcode cache, and specified APC. Please read before downvoting.

Comment: I think I'd tend to agree with ceejayoz, @ajreal. I suspect you may have simply misread/misinterpreted/mistaken what this answer is saying. `:)`

Comment: Yes, as I've tried to explain via a half dozen comments thus far - that's the key underlying bit of this question that needed answering. That he mentioned one particular opcode cache is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @ajreal, I read this answer as saying *yes, opcode caching still offers a tremendous benefit in current PHP releases, and APC is more popular than eAccelerator*. It's two sentences that answer the two points raised by the OP in the question, albeit the last perhaps in a bit of a roundabout way.

Comment: Does HipHop count as an opcode cacher, or is it something else altogether?

Comment: Ok, point taken. Soli for the dispute. But I still thinking, OP is asking whether eAccelerator is a good move (as per the title suggest). Just my opinion.

Comment: @JaredFarrish My understanding is that HipHop actually turns PHP into optimized, compiled C++ code.

Comment: Is it just that compiled C++ is more efficient than PHP opcode?

Comment: That's my understanding, yeah. It comes with some fairly significant complexities though, so for the 99.9...% of the sites out there without Facebook's traffic APC may be the better option.

Comment: Yeah, I was either watching or reading something the other day that was talking about the complexities their developers have to go through to work on Facebook. They developed a HipHop virtual machine to do development work on, for instance, and HipHop is supposedly pretty quirky and only about 60% complete.

Comment: Here is the article: [Facebook looks to fix PHP performance with HipHop virtual machine](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/12/facebook-looks-to-fix-php-performance-with-hiphop-virtual-machine.ars), in case you're interested...

Answer (score 1):

No, eAccelerator is no longer actively maintained (as no evidence exists demonstrate it is).

I would say it's worth the effort to go forward with APC or another, more modern and actively maintained accelerator technology. If you are looking for OP code caching technology, go with [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), which is popular, [has more library support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), and is actively maintained. It will also apparently be [included in a future PHP 6 release](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#add-an-opcode-cache-to-the-distribution-apc).

You might read [this answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930954/466826), which suggests that eAccelerator may be viable if you take into account the deficiencies (probable lack of PHP 6 support, older and apparently unmaintained, etc.) and still want to use something you have a certain preexisting comfort level. It just depends on your needs and the environment you work in.

Comment: I gave my vote to APC, too, so I'm not sure where this little persecution complex tantrum is coming from...

Comment: I said yes, an opcode cache is beneficial. It was quite clear, and no, I'm not voting to close, as "is an opcode cache beneficial" has an empirical yes/no answer.

Comment: This question is asking for an opinion, can't you just vote to close?

Comment: Again, this question is about eAccelerator worth to install.

Comment: And the answer is that while eAccelerator is a bad idea, the underlying tech of opcode caching is an absolutely good idea to install. Just because it was an overly specific question to start doesn't means something positive and educational can't come of it.

Comment: This is dispute, OP is well aware on the caching is to boost performance.

Comment: If that were the case, the question wouldn't say "I've read elsewhere that with PHP 5, the need for add-ons **like** eaccelerator has decreased".

Comment: No, you have to refer to the previos sentence `Back in the PHP 4 Jurassic Era, I often installed a PHP extension called 'eaccelerator' to boost the performance of PHP by caching the compiled byte code.`.

Comment: Just to make life confusing, development on eAccelerator seems to have restarted, with a new site and a bunch of commits over the last couple of months