# Switch from IIS 7.5 to Apache

Tags: performance, apache, iis, switch-statement, apc

I am concidering making a switch from IIS 7.5 to Apache.
I have already tried running PHP (FastCGI) on nginx but the performance was extremely bad compared to IIS 7.5

Because I am unable to find performance benchmarks (PHP) between IIS and Apache on Windows, I am asking you for your experience/feedback.
I use WinCache on IIS, and I have used eAccelerator on Apache. What about APC?

The switch will be for performance gain only.

**Update:** I have tried running Apache with mod_php & mod_apc. But the website felt noticeably slower than with IIS. Is this normal? The application is fully APC supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC is going to be included in PHP 6, and I'd guess it has been chosen for good reason :)
allthough it performs very well, but not as good as eAccelerator. And it has compatability issues with Zend Optimizer.

- Source: [apc vs eaccelerator vs xcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache)