# Symfony2 app not works after cache clear

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, centos, symfony-2.1, cpanel

I'm deploying a Symfony2 app in CentOS server with Cpanel.

First time that I execute the app runs well, but the problem comes When I do cache clear, then app not works more, and put this error.

Class "Propa\PageBundle\Entity\Page" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

To enter in site: http://propa.estudi83.com/app_dev.php/es/empresa/

What Can I do ?

UPDATE: Resolved the problem was eAccelerator, I'm uninstalled eAccelerator and installed APC and works fine!!

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Is there any cache optimizer installed on the machine? APC or something?

Comment: Resolved the problem was eAccelerator, I'm uninstalled eAccelerator and installed APC and works fine!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a cache optimizer issue. If you are using eAccelerator, then you will have problems, probably with Doctrine. The reason is eAccelerator removes annotations from the code! You can try APC which performs well with doctrine.

Read [apc vs eaccelerator vs xcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930877/apc-vs-eaccelerator-vs-xcache)

Comment: Resolved the problem was eAccelerator, I'm uninstalled eAccelerator and installed APC and works fine!!