# Reduce server resources and compilation of php to C++

Tags: php, c++, memory, cpu

I've searched tutorials of how to reduce server resources (CPU, memory...) in a website, using php (if it's possible) , but in vain (maybe I couldn't choose good keywords).

If the only way to manage server ressources is the c++ language (php compiled to ). How can we write a c++ code that can do this task (without using facebook's hiphop). and how does this c++ file work in a server ? (I'll be glad for some tutorials about that!).

I've worked with memcached to reduce connections to the database, But I don't know if it can do all the task.

thank you in advance.

Comment: How much traffic are you getting that server resources are an issue?  Are you on a dedicated server?  Have you tried to determine what hte bottle-neck is?

Comment: I'm not yet using any kind of servers... But I'm planning to use a dedicated server, and I want to know all about how some social networks reduce their CPU usage (exactly, how does hiphop work???)

Comment: Without knowing your bottleneck, it's impossible to know what to "fix".  First rule of optimization: *Don't do it*.  Second rule of optimization: *Don't Do It Yet (for Experts only)*.  Wait until you have a problem, then fix it...

Comment: Actual social network sites use more than one server, for load balancing, failover, redundancy, supporting millions of users, database, caching, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Okey, it's just a curiousity that comes before its time :-)

Comment: There are millions of sites on the web that run perfectly happily with php. So unless you start a website the blossoms to a million users in a week (with continued growth) you are unlikely to have problems. If your website does blossom like that you can hire somebody to the programming work while you rake in the cash. Learn the fundamentals of good design first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to do this at all.

There are lots of opcode caching like, [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) - this will compile PHP script into opcode cache and the cache is reusable until the PHP script updated again or the date validity exceeded.

**What is opcode cache?**

[Which PHP opcode cacher should I use to improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716/which-php-opcode-cacher-should-i-use-to-improve-performance)

PS: **eAccelerator** is dead (not longer maintained)

Comment: thank you! this seems like memcached! but why did facebook use the c++ then??

Comment: +1 for APC as it has native PHP support starting PHP 6, but there are more to choose from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

Comment: @Simo: 400 billion PHP-based page views every month.

Comment: @Martin This's very huge number!

Comment: @Simo: Its facebook view count. Unless you start to approach that number then stick to straight PHP.