# How to test memcache is working fine in the application

Tags: testing

the project in which i am working currently as a QA, we are going to implement memcache and opcode cache in our application.
So as a QA point of view, what are the key areas that i should test ? It would be good, if i got some brief idea about the testing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For a cache you should look at the hit ratio and adjust your cache accordingly. There're many improvements that can be done from caching. If you use PHP you can read more from this question:

[Which PHP opcode cacher should I use to improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716/which-php-opcode-cacher-should-i-use-to-improve-performance)